# How do i display user name signed with firebase authentication to my project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am working an e commerce website using next js and firebase for the authentiction and as my database source . However , i figured out how to signin with firebase authenticatiion . I am trying to figure outhow to display my users information i.e name in the header component of my project

Here is is the firebase config file

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

// Initialize Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);}
    

export{firebase}
```

Here is my header component .  i want to display it i the HELLO PART

```
import Image from "next/image";
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

import firebase from "../Firebase/Firebase";
// import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/client"

import { MenuIcon, SearchIcon, ShoppingCartIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
function Header() {






    const auth = getAuth();
    const customer = auth.currentUser;
    if (user !== null) {
        // The user object has basic properties such as display name, email, etc.
        const displayName = user.displayName;
        const email = user.email;
        const photoURL = user.photoURL;
        const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;

        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
        // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
        // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
        const uid = user.uid;
    }

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user !== null) {
        // The user object has basic properties such as display name, email, etc.
        const displayName = user.displayName;
        const email = user.email;
        const photoURL = user.photoURL;
        const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;

        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
        // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
        // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
        const uid = user.uid;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex items-center bg-amazon_blue p-1 flex-grow py-2">
                {/* top nav */}
                <div className=" mt-2 flex items-center flex-grow sm:flex-grow-0">
                    <Image src="https://links.papareact.com/f90"
                        width={150}
                        height={40}
                        objectFit="contain"
                        className="cursor-pointer"

                    />
                </div>

                {/* bottom nav */}

                {/* Search bar */}
                <div className="hidden sm:flex items-center h-10  cursor-pointer flex-grow rounded-md bg-yellow-400 hover:bg-yellow-500">
                    <input className="p-2 h-full w-6 flex-grow flex-shrink rounded-l-md focus:outline-none px-4 " type="text" />
                    <SearchIcon className="h-12 p-4" />
                </div>
                {/* Rigth */}
                <div className="text-white flex items-center text-xs space-x-6 mx-6 whitespace-nowrap">
                    <div onClick={SigninWithFirebase} className="signIn cursor-pointer links">
                        <p>`hello ${displayName}`</p>
                        <p className="font-extrabold md:text-sm">Account & list</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="cursor-pointer  links">
                        <p>Returns</p>
                        <p className="font-extrabold md:text-sm">Orders</p>

                    </div>
                    <div className="cursor-pointer  relative links flex items-center">
                        <span className="absolute top-0 right-0 md:right-10 h-4 w-4 bg-yellow-400 text-center rounded-full text-black font-bold"> 0</span>
                        <ShoppingCartIcon className="h-10" />
                        <p className="hidden md:inline font-extrabold md:text-sm mt-2">Basket</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className="space-between flex items-center space-x-3 p-2 pl-6 bg-amazon_blue-light text-white text-sm ">

                <p className="link flex items-center">
                    <MenuIcon className="h-6 mr-1" />
                    All
                </p>

                <p className="link">Men</p>
                <p className="link">Women</p>
                <p className="link">Shoes</p>
                <p className="link ">Accessories </p>
                <p className="link hidden lg:inline-flex">Latest</p>
                <p className="link hidden lg:inline-flex">Latest</p>
                <p className="link hidden lg:inline-flex">Latest</p>




            </div>
        </div>


    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: my friend you might want to do a little bit more looking into 1) the firebase v9 js sdk (you are misusing it; you shouldn't be calling `firebase.auth()`) and 2) handling state in react - keep in mind `Header` is called on *every render*, and there's definitely some logic in there that you only want to run once. If you want your app to react to the auth state then you will need to use hooks to store that state, or use some state management library like mobx to store the state, which can then be referenced in your components.

Comment: A friendly advice: remove/change to placeholders real keys and ids from firebase config. ASAP